# Finding a setting which controls `emacs` startup

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

**How can you change the commnad `emacs` startup the standard Emacs?**

I run `emacs` and get `XEmacs` as an editor in an external window. I would like to get the default Emacs inside Ubuntu's terminal.

`which emacs` gives me `/usr/bin/emacs` which seems to be the normal Emacs.
I could of course make an alias for `emacs`. However, I see that this is not the right solution, since other apps may not then see the alias, but use the setting which makes `XEmacs` my default Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal,

```
sudo update-alternatives -–config emacs
```

and choose emacs there

Comment: This works for debian based distributives :)

Comment: Use the *-nw* option to make Emacs use the console instead of opening its own window.

Comment: Please, fix this `-config` to this `--config`. - Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It is strange that I get this `(/usr/bin/emacs22). Nothing to configure.` after running the command, although I have xEmacs, Emacs and MicroEmacs in my Ubuntu.

Comment: The message also says this `There is only 1 program which provides emacs`.

Comment: @Masi, hm, try --config emacsclient. I've just tried this myself and xemacs also don't want to become alternative to emacs on my computer. But then again, 'emacs' starts emacs, not xemacs here.

Comment: @Masi, take a look at /etc/alternatives, see if there are any emacs like links that points to xemacs. If there isn't any, then your problem is somewhere else. If there is, update-alternative --config link-name will help you.

Comment: @Lars, sudo update-alternatives --config emacs22 and chose normal emacs there, not gtk version would do the same but in Ubuntu way.

Comment: Thank you for the last three comments! The **/etc/alternatives** is really good to keep in mind.